Display a User_Employee Private Information in Odoo 17
In my odoo 17 community , i created one user and that user also employee . now iwas login as an user and open his account in employee .** i can't see my own private information record**. this is my problem , i don't want to see other user or employee private informtion but i need see only my information. if i login as an administrative , i could see all employee informtions but to login as an employee user i can't see my information , so how to enable this one , please explain if any group or record rule need for this feature .i shared my screenshots please help me .....
image1
image2
image3
image4
login as an employee user i can't see my information , so how to enable this one , please explain if any group or record rule need for this feature

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
